# Issues with apt-get update & installing Curl

Tags: linux, curl, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install CURL for PHP. I have setup a Ubuntu 14 server.

I am running

```
sudo apt-get update && install php5-curl
```

I am getting the following error

```
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease

Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'host'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'host'
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'host'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'host'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'host'

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'host'

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'host'

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'host'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
install: missing destination file operand after ‘php5-curl’
Try 'install --help' for more information.
```

There are a few errors with sudo apt-get updated too. When I try to do

```
ping us.archive.ubuntu.com
```

I am getting a response.

If I try to do a standalone

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

I get the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php5-curl
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Guarav -

You are running into issues with the apt-get update command, and subsequently having an issue installing the php5-curl package.

You stated you are able to ping us.archive.ubuntu.com though, so domain name resolution is occurring, but it does not work with apt-get. Apt-get has a lot of problems I've experienced with IPv6 on certain networks. Try running the update with just IPv4 with this:

```
apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true update
```

And if that works, you can disable IPv6 permanently by creating a file in the /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ folder (it can be named anything, for example 99force-ipv4) with this line in it:

```
Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";
```

Comment: Hi GrandPackard, I am still getting the same errors with forced IPv4.

Comment: Just for troubleshooting sake, try doing a wget us.archive.ubuntu.com and see if that works, If so, then it's definitely something with apt-get

Comment: I actually gave up trying to resolve the issue. Since its a small project, I installed Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 and it worked on it.

Comment: @GauravMehta I'm sorry to hear that you weren't able to get it working and it required a reinstall. I'm glad you found a resolution though!